# How does the ECDSA in C# work

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, cryptography

I'm looking at this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ecdsacng.aspx and I'm trying to understand how is it possible that a man-in-the-middle attack would not work against this? Also, how would this differ from using a Certificate like SSL does?

Comment: Looks like a nice question for http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Henk: CSTheory is for theoretical computer science. I'd try the security.SE beta site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this cryptosystem alone is not immune to MITM attacks

all public key cryptosystems are prone to MITM regardless of their design

you need a public key infrastructure or common trusted third party to make sure an attacker can not provide his own keys as the keys of alice and/or bob

Comment: Yeah thats what I was thinking. My question would then be, what exactly is this functionality good for?

Comment: it does elliptic curve DSA calculations for you? or if the question is more like "why use ECDSA instead of DSA?" have a look at the key length ... public DSA key, 1024 bits ... public ECDSA key, 160 bits ... ~ same security strengh, but faster calculations

Comment: Well my goal is to use something like the digital signature to overcome the man-in-the-middle attack that can be done against ECDH and I thought that if the public key initialization in ECDH was verified with the ECDSA that would eliminate it but I'm not sure how Certificates fit into this. I was hoping to be able to have a private way of validating it between my C# client and C# service.

Comment: to make it simple: think of a certificate as a bag. you put in some sort if ID (a name, an address, a customer no., etc) the public key that belongs to that ID, and other data that needs to be authentic like an expiration date (when will this key expire), or whatever you need. when all data for the cert is there, you hash everything in the bag, and sign the hash with the private key of the trusted third party. everyone that has the pub key of that thrid party can verify that the contents of the cert are valid or not. the attacker can no longer forge keys for arbitrary IDs